# Read Excel file into ADODB recordset

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I have an Excel VBA application that reads information from other excel files using ADODB recordsets.  This application was working just fine, but a company software update just broke it (I guess, can't explain otherwise).

Copied below is a stripped down version that replicates the error I'm getting (also shown below).  I've tried to review the many posts that reference Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0, but I'm not sure this is related.  They all reference a specific error that I'm not seeing.

The identified error is caused by the CN.Open command.  Thanks to comment from Matt'sMug, I have determined that I can execute the connection with no issue, provided the subject workbook is already open in Excel. If it is closed (as it should be), the error returns. Any ideas?

[image]

```
Public Sub GetExcelContent()
Dim Excelbook As String
Dim CN As ADODB.Connection, RS As ADODB.Recordset

Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H1

Excelbook = Sheets(1).Cells(4, 3)

Set CN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

CN.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source= " & Excelbook & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
RS.Open "SELECT * FROM [M2_F$]", _
CN, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

End Sub
```

Comment: And which instruction is throwing the error? Is it upon opening the connection or the recordset? Did you try hitting that [Debug] button? Does the data look like a database table (rows and columns), with consistent-looking data types?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail.  It is the CN.Open command which causes the error.  The excel content is a pretty typical table of data, with headers in row 1.
HOWEVER, While investigating I determined that I can execute the connection with no issue, provided the subject workbook is already open in Excel.  If it is closed (as it should be), the error returns.

Comment: That's valuable, useful information, it should be in the post itself - feel free to [edit] to clarify anytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I have not figured out why the previous provider has ceased to work.  However, I was able to switch to an alternate that works just as well.  The coding is a little cleaner as well, so I'm happy.  Here's my new protocol:

```
Dim CN as New ADODB.Connection
Dim RS as New ADODB.Recordset
Cstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= " & Excelbook & _
     & "; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';"
CN.Open Cstring
RS.Open "SELECT * FROM [M3_F$]", CN, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
```